# What path is the issue.ignore.path element in lint.xml relative to?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, lint

According to [Android Studio Documentation - Lint](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/lint.html) We can write lint.xml this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<lint>
    <issue id="ObsoleteLayoutParam">
        <ignore path="res/layout/activation.xml" />
        <ignore path="res/layout-xlarge/activation.xml" />
    </issue>
</lint>
```

to white-list a specific path, but the doc does not specify if the path is relative or absolute. From the appearance of the sample It seems to be relative but it does not specify what the path is relative to. This is even more confusing when I have several source paths set up in build.gradle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After intensive tests, the conclusion is:

**It is either absolute or relative.** (Probably both? Have not tested though).

When it is relative, it is **relative to the root of the module** (where build.gradle is located).

You can always use **/ wild card like `<ignore path="**/res/layout/activation.xml" />` to make it relative to any path.

Clarification:

- It is not relative to where lint.xml is located (In case you have set up another path for lint.xml with android.LintOptions.lintConfig)
- It is not related to the sources you have set up with android.sourceSets

Comment: FYI, there's no difference between `*` and `**`